# Regex alternation optional replace

Tags: regex, alternation, regex-alternation

I would like to make my life translating Objective-C to Swift easier; I'm currently writing a program that will match certain often-used constructions (such as methods, properties and variables) and replace them with the Swift version. Now I'm trying to replace the +/- in front of a method name optionally to either `class` if `+` or nothing if `-`.

I can't seem to find how I can make the alternation `(\+|-)` be replaced with either `class` or  based on the choice. Is this possible in pure regex? Or do I need to put this in my application logic?

Edit: expected input and output:

`- (void)composeView(...)` gives `func composeView(...)`

`+ (void)composeView(...)` gives `class func composeView(...)`

Comment: can you put an input sample and expected output?

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain?

Comment: I haven't downvoted but I think the downvote might be related to the lack of research for your question. Community usually gets mad when questions don't demonstrate any level of research.

Comment: It doesn't really bother me, it bothers me that someone downvoted me without leaving a comment why. This helps nobody. And I did research, I just wanted a feature that didn't exist, which is why I asked if I might be looking with the wrong search terms.

Comment: well, I understand, same happened to me many times with the answers. Did it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two regex, the first one can be:

```
- \(\w+\)(composeView\(.*?\))
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/yX0cC7/1)**

Take a look at the `Substitution` section

[image]

And the second one:

```
\+ \(\w+\)(composeView\(.*?\))
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/yX0cC7/2)**

[image]

Comment: So you're saying that something like an `inline if` is not possible in regex? If so, this is probably the best possible answer.

Comment: @vrwim you can do `if` with regex but you can't decide what to replace. So, the best thing is two regex... is simpler and easier

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction for search terms on this regex `if`?

Comment: @vrwim sure, you can take a look at this link http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html